# How to use Sugar ORM's count() method?

Tags: android, sugarorm, android-database

I have an Email_Message class in my android app that stores email messages. It has an int field called "messageType". messageType == 1 means it's an inbox email, messageType == 2 means it's a sent email.

I just started with Sugar ORM and I want to check in a class how many inbox email do I have stored in the database. More accurately I want to check if I have inbox emails stored there or not, deciding if I need to fetch emails from network or database. But I cant make this if statemant work:

```
if((int)Email_Message.count(Email_Message.class, "messageType = ?", "1") == 0){} //no emails stored
```

It says the 3rd argument needs to be a String[] and I dont understand what should I put there then, the only example I could find for usage is [this one](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Clean-Persistence-with-Sugar-ORM). (long numberOfAuthors = Author.count(Author.class, "full_name = ?", "Timothy");)

Can someone explain to me how to use the count method correctly?

**EDIT**: I have to go now, but later I'll check and update the question if `String[] test = {"1"};
            if((int)Email_Message.count(Email_Message.class, "messageType = ?", test) == 0)`

does the trick or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if((int)Email_Message.count(Email_Message.class, "message_type = 1", null) == 0)
```

This worked for me, turns out Sugar ORM also likes to rename the variables like this.

Comment: You shouldn't get into the habit of specifying the rvalue for searches in the query text, use the ? operator and an array of values like in @suyang's response for safety.

Answer (score 3):

One example to use String[]:

```
String[] vals = {
    String.valueOf(LocalRecord.ImageState.Raw)
};
long n_count = HourFolder.count(HourFolder.class, "state = ?", vals);
```